# How to reset SceneKit pointOfView camera

Tags: swift, scenekit, pointofview

I an new to `SceneKit`. Trying to figure out, how I can reset the `pointOfView` camera to it original zoom/position so it would cover all nodes in the scene?

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneKitView: SCNView! //Your SCNView

var myCamera:SCNNode!  //An object to hold your scene's camera
```

In viewDidLoad, load it with hyour camera's name:

```
myCamera:SCNNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "sceneCamera", recursively: true)!
// sceneCamera is my camera node's name in .scn file

sceneKitView.allowsCameraControl = true //Allow camera control
```

When you want to **reset** it:

```
sceneKitView.allowsCameraControl = false
sceneKitView.pointOfView = myCamera
```

Keep coding......... :)

Answer (score 2):

Just setup a default camera position and orientation to desired values. Use the following code:

```
func resetCameraToDefaultPosition() {

    sceneView.pointOfView?.position = SCNVector3(x: 5, y: 0, z: 5)
    sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: .pi/4)
}
```

Also, as **@mnuages** proposed, you can use `defaultCameraController` instance property to frame all the nodes with 3D geometry in your scene:

```
func resetCameraToDefaultPosition() {

    sceneView.defaultCameraController.frameNodes([coneNode, sphereNode, cubeNode])
}
```

But the better way is to create a new camera. [Here's what Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview):

> Use a node with an SCNCamera instance assigned to its camera property to view a scene. The node provides the position and direction of a virtual camera, and the camera object provides rendering parameters such as field of view and focus.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, z: CGFloat)
cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, z: CGFloat, w: CGFloat)

let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.focalLength = 24
cameraNode.camera = camera
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`frameNodes(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontroller/2875846-framenodes) method on [`SCNCameraController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncameracontroller) to place a camera so that a set of nodes becomes visible.

Comment: This is a good and simple idea. But `self.sceneView.defaultCameraController.frameNodes(self.scene.rootNode.childNodes)` just isn't taking effect.